# Android: ListView can't click items

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I created a `ListView` with a new adapter. Each item in a row contains a photo and a subtitle. When I click on an item, I need to turn to another class and then show the details. And I generate data using a java class called **XMLPeopleParser** which get data from the raw `xml` file which is already put data.
I am defining a `setOnItemClickListener` but when clicking an item, nothing happens.
Also, the photo in each row couldn't be added. 
Any help will be appreciated!

`MainActivity.class`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class List_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView list = null;
    private TextView mselection = null;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;


    private XMLPeopleParser parser = null;
    private String [] names = null;
    private String [] addresses = null;
    private String [] images = null;

    private Person [] data = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mselection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

        parser = new XMLPeopleParser(getApplicationContext());
        names = parser.getNames();
        addresses = parser.getAddresses();
        images = parser.getImages(); 
        data = parser.getData();


        list.setAdapter(new IconicAdapter(this));


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on " + names[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                mselection.setText(names[position]);

            }
        });  
    }


    private class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        Activity context;

        IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_row, data);
            this.context = context;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView name_title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name_title);
            TextView address_title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.address_title);


            name_title.setText(names[position]);
            address_title.setText(addresses[position]);


            int[] ImageIds = new int[images.length];
            String[] ImageNames = new String[images.length];

            ImageNames[position] = images[position].substring(0, images[position].indexOf("."));
            ImageIds[position] = getResources().getIdentifier(ImageNames[position], "drawable", getPackageName());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ImageId is:  " + position + "  " + ImageNames[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            icon.setImageResource(ImageIds[position]);

            return (row);

        }
    }

}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ww.custom_list_a.List_Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/selection"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

`list_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_title"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address_title"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

`XMLPeopleParser.class`

```
public class XMLPeopleParser {

    private Person [] data = null;
    private Context context = null;

    public XMLPeopleParser(Context c){

        this.context = c;

        // grab the data from the xml
        // get the doc parser ready for people.xml
        InputStream is = this.context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.people);
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        Document doc = null;

        try{
            builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(is);
        }catch (Exception e){}


        NodeList nameList = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
        NodeList addressList = doc.getElementsByTagName("address");
        NodeList dobList = doc.getElementsByTagName("dob");
        NodeList colourList = doc.getElementsByTagName("color");
        NodeList imageList = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");
        NodeList urlList = doc.getElementsByTagName("url");




        data = new Person[nameList.getLength()];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

            String name = nameList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            String address = addressList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            String dob = dobList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            String colour = colourList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            String image = imageList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            String url = urlList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

            data[i] = new Person(name, address, dob, colour, image, url);

        }
    }

    public Person [] getData(){return data;}

    public Person getData(int i) {return data[i];}

    public String[] getNames(){
        String[] names = new String[data.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i ++){

            names[i] = getData(i).getName();
        }
        return names;
    }

    public String[] getAddresses() {
        String[] addresses = new String[data.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            addresses[i] = getData(i).getAddress();
        }
        return  addresses;
    }

    public String[] getDobs() {
        String[] dobs = new String[data.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            dobs[i] = getData(i).getDob();
        }
        return  dobs;
    }

    public String[] getColours() {
        String[] colours = new String[data.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            colours[i] = getData(i).getColour();
        }
        return  colours;
    }

    public String[] getImages() {
        String[] images = new String[data.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            images[i] = getData(i).getImage();

        }
        return  images;
    }

    public String[] geturls() {
        String[] urls = new String[data.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            urls[i] = getData(i).getUrl();
        }
        return  urls;
    }


}
```

`R.raw.people` xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="people.xsd" generated="2011-11-05T23:09:59">

    <person>
        <name>ANDY</name>
        <address>USA</address>
        <color>BLACK</color>
        <dob>2020/2/2</dob>
        <image>andy.jpeg</image>
        <url>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/andy</url>
    </person>


    <person>
        <name>Bill</name>
        <address>UK</address>
        <dob>2020/1/1</dob>
        <color>white</color>
        <image>bill.jpeg</image>
        <url>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bill</url>
    </person>
```

Comment: You have an `<ImageButton>` in your item layout that's consuming the click. You're treating it as an `ImageView` in the code, though, so if you don't need it to be an `ImageButton`, change it to an `<ImageView>`, and the `OnItemClickListener` should work then. We'd need more information for the photo issue, like what exactly the `String`s are in `images`.

Comment: @Mike: yes! after changed it into Imageview it works. I will update the XMLParser as well

Comment: @Mike already uploaded

Comment: Is the `Toast` showing the correct name? If so, are you sure you have an image by that name in your `res/drawable*/` folders somewhere? What's the ID returned from `getIdentifier()`? As a side note, the arrays there are rather useless, since they're created anew for each item, and only one value ever gets assigned in each. A simple `int` and `String` would suffice.

Comment: @MikeM.  The folder is correct and the name is correct, just like Andy.jpeg will show Andy only. But I don’t know why all of the id showed 0.

Comment: `Andy` or `andy`? Everything should be lowercase everywhere.

Comment: @MikeM.  About the array, actually I have many data and I though it would be an array for each attribute to show such as each name on the list item using position? I’m not sure.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about the arrays, for now. Just make sure all names are lowercase everywhere; i.e., in the XML, and all the image names.

Comment: @MikeM. It was my mistake. All of them are lowercase

Comment: If you temporarily change the `icon.setImageResource()` call to use `R.drawable.andy` directly, what happens?

Comment: I just realized that I might have misunderstood your last comment? Did you get the photo thing working?

Comment: yep already get! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove following code from your listActivity class:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on " + names[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                mselection.setText(names[position]);

            }
        });
```

in your IconicAdapter after:

```
ImageNames[position] = images[position].substring(0, 
images[position].indexOf("."));
            ImageIds[position] = getResources().getIdentifier(ImageNames[position], "drawable", getPackageName());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ImageId is:  " + position + "  " + ImageNames[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            icon.setImageResource(ImageIds[position]);
```

and before:

```
return (row);
```

Use this for your each row to respond onClick:

```
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // Do here whatever you want to do upon click
            });
```

Comment: This will work like a charm. If it works for you then buddy dont forget to mark this post as answer. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `list_row.xml` is not proper so it may be possible your cell hit not working. Can you please try this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="ABC" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="ABC" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```